# Regex validation of filename failing

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate a filename having letters "CAT" or "DOG" followed by 8 numerics, and ending in ".TXT".

Examples:

```
CAT20000101.TXT
DOG20031212.TXT
```

This would NOT match:

```
ATA12330000.TXT
CAT200T0101.TXT
DOG20031212.TX1
```

Here's the regex I am trying to make work:

```
(([A-Z]{3})([0-9]{8})([\.TXT]))\w+
```

Why is the last section `(.TXT)` failing against non-matching file extensions?

See example: http://regexr.com/3a7fo

Comment: `[\.TXT]` matches one single character - either `.`, `T` or `X`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside character class there is no regex grouping hence `[\.TXT]` is not right.

You can use this regex:

```
^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{8}\.TXT$
```

For only matching `CAT` and `DOG` use:

```
^(CAT|DOG)[0-9]{8}\.TXT$
```

Answer (score 1):

1. lose the unnecessary parentheses

`[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{8}[\.TXT]\w+`

2. lose the unnecessary/pattern-breaking character class `[]` around `\.TXT`

`[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{8}\.TXT\w+`

3. lose the `\w+` at the end

`[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{8}\.TXT`

4. change `[A-Z]{3}` to `(?:CAT|DOG)`.

`(?:CAT|DOG)[0-9]{8}\.TXT`

voilà.

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because `\.TXT` is in square brackets, which matches only one of those four characters. Just use `(\.TXT)`.

Answer (score 1):

remove square brackets around [.TXT] to .TXT
Your example modified http://regexr.com/3a7fu